# Fetching E-mails 10 by 10 or n by n using Imap_tools python

Tags: python, imap-tools

I'm using [Imap_tools](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/) library and I'm trying to fetch the emails in a folder 10 by 10 (for pagination and performance purposes) when I tried using limit and passing a tuple to it like so:

```
mails = mailbox.fetch(reverse = True, headers_only = True, mark_seen=False, limit=(10,20))
```

I got the following error

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\imap_tools\mailbox.py", line 147, in fetch
    assert type(limit_range) is slice
AssertionError
```

Is there anyone who has a solution or a better approach? I will be thankful!

Expected it to ignore the 1st 10 Emails and fetch the second 10 Emails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the library is looking for a slice :
`(10, 20)` => `slice(11, 21)`
11th mail to 20th mail for a total of 10 mails, considering first mail's index is 1.

Comment: Bro, you're the best! worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Function - **sliсe**:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Also there is example:
https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/fetch_by_pages.py